# Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat eece.pkg350.MultiThreadedServer$ServerThread.run

Tags: java

i was writing a client server application in java where the client has certain functions to do and the server should access the data base and send back to the client. the function login will go to the data base and check if that user exists and send the corresponding message from the server to the client. however i keep getting this exception : Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. how should i solve that? Thank you a lot

here is the code for my server:

```
public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            datain =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            dataout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("first IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        String res = ";";
        try
        { 

            String command = datain.readLine();
            System.out.println(command);
            if("Log In".equals(command)){

                String email = datain.readLine();
                System.out.println(email);
                String password = datain.readLine();
                System.out.println(password);
                res = jdbc.LogIn(email,password);

                /*ServerSxocket s = new ServerSocket(1927);
                socket = s.accept();*/
                System.out.println(res);
                dataout.writeBytes(res + '\n');
                //DataOutputStream  outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("closing socket");
                datain.close();
                dataout.close();
                socket.close();


            }


        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("second IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i have this function that i am using to check if a certain record exists in the database

```
   public String LogIn (String email, String password){

   int userCount = 0;
   String res = "hey";
   String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from users WHERE email = '" + email + "'";
   String p = "";
   Statement command = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   try {

       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
       command = conn.createStatement();
       rs = command.executeQuery(sql);
       userCount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(sql));

        if (userCount==1){

            res = "There is a user with this account";
        }
        if (userCount==0){

             res = "There is no account with this email";
             System.out.println(res);


         }
         else {

             sql = "SELECT password from users WHERE email = '"+email+"'";
             rs = command.executeQuery(sql);
             p = rs.getString(sql);


             if (p==password){

                  res = "correct password";
             }
             else {

                 res = "The password you entered is incorrect";
                 System.out.println(res);

             }



        }

   }
   catch(SQLException s){

       s.printStackTrace();
   }
   return res;
```

}

Comment: You probably should read about SQL injection. Also, you should post the complete stacktrace of your NPE.

Comment: Also never use `==` with `String`s!

Comment: this is the exception i am getting Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at eece.pkg350.MultiThreadedServer$ServerThread.run(MultiThreadedServer.java:103)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   is this what you mean?

Comment: i changed the == in my code now thanks for pointing that out

Comment: OK now edit your question, and add a comment at line 103 (something like `// NPE here`). I bet 1$ on `jdbc` being null

Comment: awww i have just realized it. It is null i fixed it now. I still haven't got used to this. Thank you :)

Comment: You owe me a buck :p (kidding)